# Sharepoint Lists to Reporting Database Application Using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to develop a Windows application that:

1) Consumes SharePoint 2010 List(s).
2) Inserts the consumed list(s) into a reporting database as a table.
3) Run in the background so that as the list(s) is updated, the table(s) is updated.

My thought is to use WPF to create this application but I'm not sure about how to make it run in the background like a windows service.  Of course, creating a windows service alone does not allow for a gui front end.  I need to be able to enter SharePoint configuration and reporting database configuration info into a gui before starting the program and letting it run in the background.  Any ideas as to the best way to approach this application?

Thanks in Advance

NEL

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Windows/WPF/Console app that does

a) Writes settings (sharepoint list and database connection details etc..) to a config file of a windows service application

b) Writes settings to a config file of a console app that can be scheduled to run using Task Scheduler library

You can create any UI app (preferably web/silverlight) that can communicate with a REST/web service which does

c) UI app that POST settings to a WCF/Java service which does (1), (2) and (3) for you on the server side.

Your UI can run on any user machine with access to SharePoint web services/RESTful services and reporting database(appropriate database credentials) and does not need to be on a server.

Comment: Why not run reporting directly against sharepoint lists using SSRS > ReportViewer Control ?

Comment: OP wants to build an app that pushes SharePoint list data onto a database on a scheduled basis(oracle/sql server/others..) and  configurable via UI. He might be interested in generating a report or not. He might just want to leave it there and sell it as a  product. He might use SSRS/crystal/other reporting tool.......you get the idea

Comment: Thanks Ken for your comments!